# Wifi disconnects after approximately five minutes

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

I use an HP Pavillion running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and up until now I did not have any problems with my computer's wifi connection. After about five minutes after booting, the Internet will slow down and after a few moments stop working completely, even though the wifi signal in the top right corner still shows that the computer is connected. Why does that happen?

Also, if I try to disconnect and reconnect, it will fail to connect and indefinitely spam me with wifi password requests that seemingly do not change anything.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I apologise if a question with a solution already exists, I just was unaware of my wireless card model. Will try the proposed solution in the possible duplicate.

Comment: That's not a problem. Please report the result here.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my problem. Unless something happens later, I will consider this solved. Thanks a lot!